# SQL Query optimisation for custom code, Avoiding executing query in loop

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a Query where i am fetching list of distinct serial numbers

```
SELECT DISTINCT LONG_SERIAL FROM AQD WHERE MS=?
```

After which i am looping through all the result numbers to run the below query

```
SELECT WE.EXECUTION_STATUS FROM (
SELECT MAX(NWE.EXECUTION_START) AS EXEC_START, NWE.NAP_SMALL_CELL_ID AS NSCID FROM
NAP WF EXECUTION NWE GROUP BY NWE. NAP_SMALL_CELL_ID
) B, NAP_WF_EXECUTION WE, NAP_SMALL_CELL CELL, NAP_TRANSACTION TRAN
WHERE CELL. NAP_SMALL_CELL_ID = WF.NAP_SMALL_CELL_ID
AND TRAN.NAP_TRANSACTION_ID = CELL. TRANSACTION_ID
AND B.NSCID = CELL. NAP_SMALL_CELL_ID
AND B.EXEC_START= WF.EXECUTION_START
AND CELL.SERIAL_NUMBER in (?)
ORDER BY TRAN. NAP_TRANSACTION_ID DESC;
```

Now, i want to optimise this query so i can avoid running this in loop to get each execution status of serial numbers

Comment: Like this `CELL.SERIAL_NUMBER in (SELECT LONG_SERIAL FROM AQD WHERE MS=?)`?